# Cast an Anonymous Types in Object and retrieve one Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, anonymous-types

I use C# asp.net4.

I have a method to populate a Repeater with Anonymous Types (Fields: Title, CategoryId), inside the Repeater I also placed a Label:

```
        var parentCategories = from c in context.CmsCategories
                               where c.CategoryNodeLevel == 1
                               select new { c.Title, c.CategoryId };
        uxRepeter.DataSource = parentCategories;
        uxRepeter.DataBind();
```

---

I need to change Text Properties for each label inside my Repeater on Repeater Event ItemDataBound

```
   protected void uxRepeter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("uxLabel");
        uxLabel.Text = // How to do here!!!!!!!! 
    }
```

So I need set the properties for Label.Text using e.Item (or a better way if any).

My problem I'm not able to CAST the e.Item (Anonymous type Field Title) and set it as Text Propriety for my Label.

I understand Anonymous Type can be casted to only Object Type, but in my case my Anonymous Type has Title and CategoryId Fields.

My question:

How to cast and retrieve the field with I'm interested? Thanks for your time on this?

EDIT:
SOME ERROR I RECEIVE:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32]' to type 'System.String'.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The options Joseph presents are good ones, but there *is* a horrible way you can do this. It's somewhat fragile, as it relies on you specifying the anonymous type in *exactly* the same way in two places. Here we go:

```
public static T CastByExample<T>(object input, T example)
{
    return (T) input;
}
```

Then:

```
object item = ...; // However you get the value from the control

// Specify the "example" using the same property names, types and order
// as elsewhere.
var cast = CastByExample(item, new { Title = default(string),
                                     CategoryId = default(int) } );
var result = cast.Title;
```

EDIT: Further wrinkle - the two anonymous type creation expressions have to be in the same assembly (project). Sorry for forgetting to mention that before now.

Comment: Something I've been wondering - is it merely an implementation detail that two anonymous types of the same shape are type-compatible, or is it part of the spec that they must be compatible?

Comment: @Rex: It's part of the spec. I don't have a reference on me, but basically *within the same assembly*, two anonymous type construction expressions with the same property names and types in the same order must refer to the same type.

Comment: @Rex: Deep within Section 7.6.10.6: "Within the same program, two anonymous object initializers that specify a sequence of properties of the same names and compile-time types in the same order will produce instances of the same anonymous type." (Jon, without reference, quotes the dern thing near verbatim!)

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast the anonymous type to anything because you literally have no type to cast it to, as you've basically pointed out already.

So you really have two options.

1. Don't cast to an anonymous type, but rather a known type that you build just for handling this scenario or
2. assign a dynamic variable to the item and use dynamic properties instead

Example 1:

```
var parentCategories = from c in context.CmsCategories
    where c.CategoryNodeLevel == 1
    select new RepeaterViewModel { c.Title, c.CategoryId };
```

Example 2: (also I think you're last line you meant to assign the link var)

```
protected void uxRepeter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("uxLabel");
    dynamic iCanUseTitleHere = e.Item;
    link.Text = iCanUseTitleHere.Title; //no compilation issue here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joesph for your reply. Any cons on your Example 2 instead of Ex 1? thanks for your time on this

Comment: @GibboK Well you lose your strong typing, so any dev that's touching the event handler has to already know what can be accessed on that object.  By going with the first example, you get your strong typing, and the only thing you have to know in your event handler is what class to cast e.Item into.  Everything else in known at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `dynamic` in this case. I think the code would be:

```
protected void uxRepeter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic link = (dynamic)e.Item.FindControl("uxLabel");
    uxLabel.Text = link.Title; //since 'link' is a dynamic now, the compiler won't check for the Title property's existence, until runtime.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just cast to `(typeof(new { Title = "", CategoryID = 0 }))`?