# Cast List<object> to AnonymousTypes list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have populated the follow list with objects of type `AnonymousType`

```
List<object> someList = new List<object>();

someList.Add(new { foo = 1 });
```

My problem is that I can't make it stronly typed to do something like this:

```
someList.Where(x=> x.foo == 1);
```

However, it's possible on this list:

```
var someList = new[] { new { foo = 1 } };
```

Can I cast my first list to make it behave like the second list? I want to be able to use lambda expressions on the properties like I showed above.

Comment: Why do you have a `List<object>` when its a `List<anonymous>`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because `AnonymousType` is a type of `object`. There is no such thing as an `anonymous` data type. Right?

Comment: Anonymous types only have readonly properties.

Comment: @Romoku: If you  use this type in the same method you can use the anonymous type. If you need it in a different method you should use a custom class (or `Tuple<T>`).

Comment: I realize that. Anonymous types are especially helpful in Linq queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take advantage of generics and type inference to create the list for you:

```
public static List<T> CreateAnonymousList<T>(params T[] entries)
{
    return new List<T>(entries);
}
```

Usage like:

```
var someList = CreateAnonymousList(new { foo = 1 }, new { foo = 2 }, new { foo = 1 });

someList.Where(x => x.foo == 1);
```

Naturally you won't be able to do *much* with it. You'll never be able to strongly type it in your code to anything other than `var` or return it out from your method or anything you normally wouldn't be able to do with anonymous types. If you want to do more, you'll just have to bite the (small) bullet and define a class for your anonymous type.

---

Rereading your question, you can still perform LINQ queries on an array:

```
var someArray = new[]{new { foo = 1 }, new { foo = 2 }, new { foo = 1 }};
someArray.Where(x => x.foo == 1)
```

So unless you are modifying it (say via standard `List<T>` operations like `Add` or `Remove`) then there's no reason to have to convert it to a `List<T>`.

I realize that maybe you want to still be able to pass it back (for some reason) and still do operations on it without knowing its anonymous type. In that case you *could* treat it as `dynamic` and perform the operations at runtime, but you lose any intellisense/strong typing that you'd normally have with the anonymous type:

```
List<dynamic> someDynamicList = new List<dynamic>() {new { foo = 1 }, new { foo = 2 }, new { foo = 1 }};
someDynamicList.Where(x => x.foo == 1)
```

---

One last method as pointed out by [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489322/1269654) leveraging Jon Skeet's CastByExample, but extended to convert your collection with an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CastByExample<T>(this IEnumerable source, T example)
{
    foreach(object entry in source)
        yield return (T)entry;
}

public static IEnumerable CreateAnonymousData()
{
    return new[]{new { foo = 1 }, new { foo = 2 }, new { foo = 1 }};
}
```

With usage like:

```
var anonymousData = CreateAnonymousData();
var typedAnonymousData = anonymousData.CastByExample(new { foo = 1 });
typedAnonymousData.Where(x => x.foo == 1);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that within the *same assembly*, anonymous types declared with the same parameter names, types, and *order* compile to the same type. This won't work if you need to call your `CreateAnonymousData` from outside the current assembly and you have to maintain the signature of your `foo` anonymous type everywhere you use it (add/change its signature, you *must* update it *everywhere* you use it or you're going to have a bad time).

But I think it's becoming more clear now that the best solution to this is to simply define a class representation of your anonymous type.

Comment: Quite literally 1 second behind me on `dynamic` :-p

Comment: Nice, but the problem remains though. I want it to take the generic object list as a parameter and return `var someList = new[] { new { foo = 1 } };`

Comment: Haha, yeah @ByteBlast. Serves me right for including in my edit the bit about performing LINQ on arrays before posting my edit! :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It's all good. You have good coverage here so my answer doesn't add much value. I'll remove it.

Comment: @Johan Not sure what you're asking. Do you want your method that generates the array to _return_ a `List<MyAnonymousType>` to which LINQ operations can be performed outside?

Comment: @Johan Why don't you define a class?

Comment: @Romoku Yea, I wasn't aware that it was this much work. Class it is. Chris, thanks for a good example though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Jon Skeets' [`CastByExample`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901616/284240):

```
public static T CastByExample<T>(object input, T example)
{
    return (T)input;
}

List<object> someList = new List<object>() { 
    new { foo = 1 },new { foo = 2 },new { foo = 3 }
};

var example = new { foo = 0 };

foreach (object obj in someList)
{
    var x = CastByExample(obj, example);
    Console.WriteLine("Foo: " + x.foo);
}
```

Comment: This could be taken one step further with an extension method similar to `Cast(T)`. usage: `someList.CastByExample(example).ToList();`