# Cast class to partial of same class in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, casting

My classes as entity in EF are:

```
Cat { Id, ParentId, Name, ImageUrl, ...}

Tree { Id , ParentId, Name}
```

Is there another option for:

```
var trees= (from rs in _db.ItemCats
            where rs.ParentId == null
            select new Tree
            {
                Id = rs.Id,
                ParentId = rs.ParentId,
                Name = rs.Name
            }).ToList();
```

Something like:

```
var trees= (from rs in _db.ItemCats
            where rs.ParentId == null
            select new 
            { 
                rs.Id, rs.Name, 
                rs.ParentId 
            }).Cast<Tree>().ToList();
```

But get:

> Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'Meha3.Models.Tree'.
>   LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration
>   types

Comment: Is `Cat` a subtype of `Tree`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/446039/116614.

Comment: you need to add more explanation so user can understand

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445984/convert-anonymous-type-to-class

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is "Duck" typing and .Net doesn't support "Duck" typing so you can't Cast it directly.  All of your options consist of converting it into the type you want either through mapping, a constructor on tree, reflection, etc. but an actual cast is impossible.

Appologies for links to other SO answers but I don't see the need to duplicate the details here...

[Conversion option here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/446010/2270839)

[Reflection option here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/446039/2270839)

[Yet another way by Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901616/2270839) which he specifically says is horrible... don't do it this way...

I would highly recommmend using the conversion method or constructor method.

Comment: tnx a lot dear @Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. However, not like your example. You might want to check out the [Automapper](http://automapper.org/):

Your issue if you use it will become solved like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Cat, Tree>();
var tree = Mapper.Map<Tree>(cat);
```

Comment: tnx but without Automapper

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast from the anoymous type to the Tree class since the anonymous type is not of Type Tree

You also fall foul of the various EF rules about what can and cannot be performed server side

When I have had to perform similar tasks, I have ended up having to write code like this - not elegant, but it works:

```
var trees= (from rs in _db.ItemCats
        where rs.ParentId == null
        select new 
        { 
            Id = rs.Id, 
            Name = rs.Name, 
            ParentId = rs.ParentId 
        })
        .AsEnumerable() //to run the query and take us out of the EF domain
        .Select(a => new Tree()
        {
           Id = a.Id,
           Name = a.Name,
           ParentId = a.ParentId
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: The code in the question (the version without a cast) works just fine.  There's no need for this.  He's just trying to make it shorter/simpler.  This does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten it up a bit using Lambada syntax, but not much

**Something Like This:**

```
var trees= _db.ItemCats.Select(Cat => new Tree(){
            Id = Cat.Id,
            ParentId = Cat.ParentId,
            Name = Cat.Name
        }).ToList();
```

Another Option is that if you do this often you could move the conversion to an extension method which would allow you to call something like this

```
var trees = _db.ItemCats.Select(Cat => Cat.ToTree()).ToList();
```